# Is there a 'new' modifier for methods in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, junit

Is there an equivalent to [C#'s `new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) modifier in Java?

I'd like to use it for unit tests - every init() method should be marked final and annotated with @Before. Then, jUnit executes all of these init() methods.

I don't want to bother coming up with new names for each of these init() methods, and I definitely wants to mark them as final to make sure they don't override eachother (an alternative pattern is to override and call super.init() from every init() method).

Answer (score 5):

A common pattern is to make your own 'before' methods final and create protected (abstract) methods for the subclasses.

### In the superclass

```
@Before
public final void before() {
   onBefore();
}

protected void onBefore()  {

}
```

### In the subclass

```
protected void onBefore() {
    // prepare the test fixture
}
```

This gives you the best of both worlds:

- a well-known method to override in sub-classes;
- overriding is optional;
- the superclass method is never overriden;
- the client method is invoked when the super-class decides, *i.e.* either before or after the super-class decides.

It does have a single downside - it ties you to a single super-class. Still, that may not be an issue to your environment.

Comment: The problem is indeed tying to a single base class. If a class stops inheriting the base class, then the onBefore() method never gets called.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. Heck, before `@Override` there wasn't even any way of protecting against typos when overriding.

You can't create a method with the same signature as a superclass method without it overriding that method. Admittedly I try not to do this even in C#...

Have you considered using `initFoo` and `initBar` for classes `Foo` and `Bar` respectively (etc)? It's a simple enough pattern to follow, and would avoid the name collisions. A bit ugly, admittedly.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have an equivalent to the C# `new` operator which is

> Used to hide an inherited member from a base class member.

For what you'd like to do, why not create a base class that your other tests can extend, and create an `abstract` method named `init()` (marked with `@Before`) in the base class? This forces all subclasses to supply an `init()` method.