# Is there a Java equivalent to the 'new' modifier in C#?

Tags: c#, java, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a ‘new’ modifier for methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125269/is-there-a-new-modifier-for-methods-in-java)

In c#, a subclass's method can be [modified as new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/435f1dw2.aspx).

One usage of the new modifier to explicitly hide a member inherited from a base class.

Is there a same keyword in Java?

Comment: Probably this usage of `new` is to be avoided in C#. Maybe it would be better to redesign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

In C# you use new to hide / shadow non-virtual functions of a base class. You need this keyword in C#, because you can not override functions that are non-virtual.

In Java, all functions are virtual by default, hence you can always override them and there is no need for a keyword such as new.

Hope this helps.

Comment: (And then someone goes and makes a method `final` ..)

Answer (score 2):

In C#, any method you want to override from the baseclase needs to be `abstract`, `virtual` or an `override` itself. The new keyword does actually not do an override. It works kind of different:

If you declare a function with the new-keyword, hiding a base-class's function, THIS implementation will only be used if you have an object of the very same child-type. Example:

```
class TopClass
    {
        public String getHello()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }

        public virtual String getWorld()
        {
            return "World";
        }
    }

    class ChildClass : TopClass
    {
        public new String getHello()
        {
            return "Hi";
        }

        public override string getWorld()
        {
            return "Earth";
        }
    }
```

This will result in:

```
        TopClass tc = new TopClass();
        Console.WriteLine(tc.getHello() + " " + tc.getWorld()); // Hello World

        ChildClass cc = new ChildClass();
        Console.WriteLine(cc.getHello() + " " + cc.getWorld()); // Hi Earth

        TopClass tc2 = new ChildClass();
        Console.WriteLine(tc2.getHello() + " " + tc2.getWorld()); // Hello Earth

        Console.ReadLine();
```

You can see the difference of the new keyword compared to a typical override:
If the extending class is casted to a parents ClassType, the overriding functions (return Earth instead of World) will still be in effect, while the new functions aren't (Hi is NOT returned instead of Hello).

Comment: +1 for the examples. Good to know about baseclass methods get used when cast to generic (topclass) type.